# Clean positioning of Search button in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Given the following example, what would be a good approach to position the Search button in line with the date input controls?

I gave it a shot with Bootstrap (2 rows, 3 columns) but the layout should stick to the left and keep the 3 logical columns together. And maybe there's an easier solution I am overlooking.

[JS Bin HTML](http://jsbin.com/zalerogiyi/1/edit?html,js,output)

[image: Screenshot]

Note: based on the simplified output from Telerik's Kendo UI combined with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Nevertheless I learned from the different approaches in the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox requires IE10+

Here is the solution that works everywhere and won't break bootstrap's responsiveness http://output.jsbin.com/ladezahija/1/

Idea is to apply to elements (blocks with date and search button) next rule:

```
.element {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

In an example I had to use `float: none` to redefine previously added property by bootstrap.

Also make sure you add a separate class for container and inner elements you work on.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with CSS Flex.

using this CSS would align them for you. (you will need some vendor prefixes)

```js
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: [
    { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" }
  ]
});
```

```css
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.container-fluid > div {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div style="margin: 20px; float: left;">
        <h4>
            <label for="StartDate">From</label>
        </h4>
        <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header">
            <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                <input name="startDate" class="k-input" id="startDate" role="combobox" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="startDate_dateview" style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="1-11-2015" data-val="true" data-role="datepicker" />
                <span class="k-select" role="button"  unselectable="on">
                    <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar" unselectable="on">select</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div style="margin: 20px; float: left;">
        <h4>
            <label for="EndDate">To</label>
        </h4>
        <span class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header">
            <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
                <input name="endDate" class="k-input" id="endDate" role="combobox" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="endDate_dateview" style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="24-12-2015" data-val="true" data-role="datepicker" />
                <span class="k-select" role="button"  unselectable="on">
                    <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar" unselectable="on">select</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>            
    </div>

    <div style="margin: 20px; float: left;">
        <button tabindex="0" class="k-button" id="applyFilters" role="button" aria-disabled="false" data-role="button">Search</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't used bootstrap properly. Anyway I have two solution.

First Solution:=>  Add a blank h4 `<h4>&nbsp;</h4>` into last div.

Second Solution:=> Use `margin-top:60px`   to `k-button`.